# Testing forms in symfony 2 phpunit

Tags: php, forms, unit-testing, symfony

I have a form with two fields. After submitting it, there's a redirection to the same controller that displayed that form.

The method is as follows:

```
public function chartsAction($path, Request $request)
{
   // display form

   if(isset($_POST))
   {
      // handle form submission
   }
}
```

When it's not a POST request, the URL is `charts/`.

When it's a POST request, the URL is for example `charts/dateFrom/2013-08/dateTo/2014-02`, so that's the $path argument of the method, and two variables depending on the form.

---

Now I want to test this. The problem is that the form redirection gives me the same, charts/ website. It just doesn't add $path parameter to the route. What's going on? My test method:

```
   public function testChartsAction()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/charts', [], [], $this->credintials);

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('dateChooser[Choose]')->form([
            'dateChooser[dateFrom]' => '2014-08',
            'dateChooser[dateTo]'   => '2014-12',
        ]);
        $this->client->submit($form);
        $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isRedirect('/charts/dateFrom/2014-08/dateTo/2014-12'));
        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
    }
```

First assert gives me false.

Comment: Try test isRedirect before the followRedirect method

Comment: It still gives me /charts redirect, without GET parameters from the form.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should skip "isRedirect" assert. In the form handler, you can set a success flash message, that will be rendered in the response page:

```
$client = $this->makeClient(true);
$client->followRedirects();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);

$form = $crawler->filter('#formID')->form();
$form->setValues(array(
    "formsample[firstname]" => "test firstname",
    "formsample[lastname]"  => "test lastname"
));

$client->setServerParameter("HTTP_X-Requested-With" , "XMLHttpRequest");
$client->submit($form);
$response = $client->getResponse();
$this->assertContains('Your data has been saved!', $response->getContent());
```